# Which server software outputs "Hello, A communication error occurred:" error message?

Tags: iis-7.5, azure, 503-error

This is a rewrite of [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17926150/57428). Basically I have an Azure web role (and so some load balancer and IIS 7.5) and is some cases the users get HTTP code 503 and the following error message rendered as HTML

```
Hello,
A communication error occurred: ""
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other
problems preventing it from responding to requests.
You may wish to try again at a later time.
```

which makes no sense and noone knows where to start dealing with it.

What software component is known to produce this error message and under which conditions and how could I get it reproduced reliably?

Comment: Could close-voters please explain the close votes? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the IIS has no custom error page installed, then I'd say that it is the loadbalancer. It looks like the loadbalancer is sometimes unable to connect to the backend. Maybe the load on the backends is too high?

Comment: Well, maybe, but does load balancer have any specific name?

Comment: Do you use the azure traffic manager as loadbalancer?

Comment: I don't really know. It's a web role with nothing special.